# SQL, select 2 columns which in same group in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as parents and dogs, and I am asked to

> "JOIN tables parents and dogs, and SELECT the parents and children that have the same fur type. Only show them once"

I really don't know how to do it

Table 1: parents (parent, child)

```
('abraham', 'barack')
('abraham', 'clinton')
('delano', 'herbert')
('eisenhower', 'fillmore')
('fillmore', 'abraham')
('fillmore', 'delano')
('fillmore', 'grover')
```

Table 2: dogs(name, fur)

```
('abraham', 'long')
('barack', 'short')
('clinton', 'long')
('delano', 'long')
('eisenhower', 'short')
('fillmore', 'curly')
('grover', 'short')
('herbert', 'curly')
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is do:

1. Create (parent, fur) pairs by joining both tables on the parent column from the first table and the name column from the second table
2. Create (child, fur) pairs by joining both tables, but this time on the child column
3. Create (parent, child) pair by joining the newly created tables on the fur column
4. Find intersection between the original (parent, table) column and the table created by #3

SQL:

```
SELECT parent, child FROM parents as C JOIN
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.parent, B.child
FROM (SELECT parent, 
             fur 
FROM parents 
JOIN dogs 
ON parent=name) as A
JOIN
(SELECT child,
        fur
FROM parents
ON child=name) as B
ON A.fur = B.fur) as D
ON C.parent = D.parent AND C.child = D.child
```

Comment: @Strawberry my bad didn't notice the tag. Updated.

Comment: There's far too much query here.